# Spring's produces = "application/json" not maintaining scale for double value in response

Tags: json, spring

Below is my sample Domain object which is automatically converted to json through 'produces = "application/json"'

```
    public class Total {

        private double amount;

        public double getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(double amount) {
            this.amount= amount;
        }
    }
```

Below is my sample resource which generates json from the domain object

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Total get(@RequestBody RequestDomain reqDomain) {

            Total total = new Total();
            // Here I am getting some amount in String format e.g 2.5000
            // I want to round that value to 2 decimal values

            String inputValue = "2.5000"; // Sample value(I am getting this from somewhere)

            // Rounding this value to 2 decimal places
            BigDecimal bigDec = new BigDecimal(inputValue);
            bigDec = bigDec.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

            // Setting the rounded value to domain object
            total.setAmount(bigDec.doubleValue());          
            return total;

        }
```

The json which is getting created is as follows

```
    {
        "amount" : 2.5
    }
```

I want the output having exactly two decimal places

```
    {
        "amount" : 2.50
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value of `2.5` and `2.50` are same format it where you display(in view)

Comment: In these cases you need to ask yourself "why do I need a data structure to have X decimals when the presentation layer is going to handle the output and can format it however it wants." Will it change something? Is there a need for 2 decimals at most actually?

Comment: Yes I can format it on view, but I don't want it to be formatted on view.

Comment: How could `total.setAmount(bigDec.toString())` possibly compile, since setAmount() takes a double as argument?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry I have corrected it. It was actually total.setAmount(bigDec.doubleValue());