# Big Decimal formatting after rounding

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal, price

I am having an issue with Big Decimal and its formatting after rounding. I have an input price as 35.90 and the output returns 35.9

This is how I am doing my rounding:

```
BigDecimal scaledResult = rs.getPrice().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
sc.setPrice(scaledResult);
```

which returns the 35.9 output even though I have set the scale to two decimal places. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a rounding issue (as 35.9 == 35.90), that's a formatting issue.

Comment: When you say that it *returns* 35.9, what do you mean? You output the result somewhere?

Comment: Returned by an api to client side as 35.9 although in the database it is stored as 35.90.

Comment: What do you get if you print the result of `scaledResult.toString()`?

Comment: API? Client side?  Somewhere, in some way you are converting from a `BigDecimal` to a string representation to get "35.9".  That's where your problem is.  Without a [mcve] we can't really say much more than that.

Comment: `logger.info("Scaled result {} ", scaledResult);`

print out:
Scaled result 35.90

Comment: So your BigDecimal value is correct... Maybe the API do not maintain your BigInteger's scale? Try passing the API a value such as `new BigDecimal("12.30")`... If that doesn't work, then the problem is with the API itself...

Comment: Yes I am wondering if there is an issue with maintaining the scaling, I am returning a JSON response.  I will look deeper into this, thank you

Comment: After looking into it, there seems to be a similar issue found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883453/springs-produces-application-json-not-maintaining-scale-for-double-value-in

Comment: If you want to preserve the formatting, you need to make sure the JSON value is transferred as a String, not a double.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I have used your advice and answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help, here is how I have solved it by writing a serializer:

```
public class BigDecimalSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString());
    }
}
```

and fields of my model:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalSerializer.class)
private BigDecimal price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **rounding** is **working fine**. The **reason** why you are not getting trailing zeros is that **you** are **returning** the **response** as `BigDecimal`, **instead you need** to return as `String`(as mentioned by others as well).

There is simple way of doing it using `@JsonFormat` **annotation** with `shape` as `STRING` on top of your `BigDecimal` variables in your Response Object. Refer below:

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

  class YourResponseObjectClass {

    @JsonFormat (shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private BigDecimal price;

 }
```